# Arrow pointing upwards in a Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d

I am trying to write a code for an arrow that points upwards from the center of the circle in a `Graphics3D`.

```
Manipulate[
Plot3D[RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}]*
UnitStep[(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 - 1.5^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
PlotRange -> All], {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

I want an arrow to point perpendicular from the center of this circle, how can I do that ?

Comment: Just use `VectorPlot3D`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Plot3D[ RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}] UnitStep[(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 - 1.5^2], 
                                                 {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},  PlotRange -> All], 
      Graphics3D[Arrow[{{a, b, 0}, {a, b, 1/2}}]]], 
{a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Or, to make a bigger point, a solid arrow:

```
Manipulate[Show[
  Plot3D[
   RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}]*UnitStep[(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 - 1.5^2],
   {x, -3, 3},
   {y, -3, 3},
   PlotRange -> All],
  Graphics3D[{
    White, Specularity[1],
    Cylinder[{{a, b, 0}, {a, b, 1/2}}, .2],
    Cone[{{a, b, 1/2}, {a, b, 7/8}}, .3]}]],
 {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}]
```

[image: plot]